# How do smart contracts work in waves vs. ethereum?

Tags: wavesplatform, ride

I am developing contracts in ethereum. That is quiet easy for me. However, a customer would like to have a contract on waves. He already has a token created on the Waves blockchain. Is it possible to add a smart contract to an already existing token? How do Waves smart contracts generally work compared to ethereums?

Answer (score 0):

Please check our [articles](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/articles-on-dapps.html) and [how to write a dApp](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/writing-dapps.html) using Waves [RIDE language](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/ride/about-ride.html).

The assets (tokes) that were issued without a script cannot become scripted. You can create an asset that behaves as non-scripted but can be upgraded later, by issuing an asset with a script: 'true'.